# MySQL: How far is too far with indexing? (i.e. Foreign Keys)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

Have done a small bit of database design and development, and I'm now dealing with large amounts of data here; scalability is needed and I'd like minimize duplication as much as possible too.

On a very high level

## Scenario

---

Top level Table: This table contains unique information; a Houses Address for example.

Next: Table contains data specific to the first. Details specific to the rooms in the house. How many walls it has for example, or floor size etc.

Next: Table contains details about a Person, and also what room they are in. For instance, when the Person is in the room. I guess this is a Enters Room type table.

Next: Table is what thing (e.g. couch) in the room the person interacts with.

Finally: What action the person has actually done with the thing in the room.

---

My question is, what level of indexing is unnecessary, or is it ever unnecessary to index rather than replicate?

```
Houses Table -> Rooms Table -> Enters Room Table -> Thing Table -> Interaction Table
```

and of course Person has details about it too

```
Enters Room Table -> Person
```

Person has details about it too though. This is where I get kind of *iffy*

```
Person: Nationality -> Nationality Table
Person: Name -> Name Table
Person: *Potentially Replicable Piece of Data* -> Subsequent table
```

It just seems like it's more efficient to replace Replicable data other than for example a persons age (2 digits), than to have a database with loads of instances of the word 'Ireland', instead of just a '#'

Is there a bad side to this? Or is this good practice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking about indexing or hierarchy/database design?  They aren't the same thing.  I assume you're asking about if it's a good idea to have a lot of foreign keys in your tables that relate to other tables?

Comment: @Siyual Yeah that is what I am asking I guess. I was giving an example of the design to try and make it easier to envision the tables that may have almost only index values

Comment: I think you're confusing indexes with foreign keys.  They're different things.  But having references to an existing record in a different table, rather than replicating the data is good practice.  It really just depends on the data though.  Most cases it's a good idea, some cases it's not.

Comment: Ah sorry yes I have used index in place of foreign keys. My mistake, I've never really implemented indexes independently of foreign keys so I guess I interchanged them. Thanks!